# enable oracle SQL constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

someone who can help me, disable the constraint of a table in the database using cascade, the problem I have now is that I don't know how I can enable everything using cascade or how I can validate that everything is enabled again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `cascade enable` foreign key constraints, if that's what you are asking - you'll have to do it manually. It's not that complicated; have a look at the following example.

There are some foreign key constraints in my schema that are disabled:

```
SQL> select table_name, constraint_name, status
  2  from user_constraints where constraint_type = 'R';

TABLE_NAME                     CONSTRAINT_NAME                STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------
EMP                            FK_EMP_DEPT                    DISABLED
BONUS                          FK_BON_EMP                     DISABLED
```

The following script searches for such a constraints (in `USER_CONSTRAINTS`) and enables them in a loop, using dynamic SQL (as you can't perform DDL in PL/SQL otherwise):

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(400);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select table_name, constraint_name
  5                  from user_constraints
  6                  where constraint_type = 'R' and status = 'DISABLED'
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      l_str := 'alter table ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 10               '  enable constraint ' || cur_r.constraint_name;
 11      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 12      execute immediate l_str;
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /
alter table EMP  enable constraint FK_EMP_DEPT
alter table BONUS  enable constraint FK_BON_EMP

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The result: they are enabled:

```
SQL> select table_name, constraint_name, status
  2  from user_constraints where constraint_type = 'R';

TABLE_NAME                     CONSTRAINT_NAME                STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------
EMP                            FK_EMP_DEPT                    ENABLED
BONUS                          FK_BON_EMP                     ENABLED

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful